# CKEditor.net table class

Tags: asp.net, plugins, ckeditor

In a asp.net C# webapp I'm using the CKEditor 3.6.2 and I'm facing the following problem:

In my stylesheet I have a CSS class to use in tables and I'm trying to bring this class already filled in the "Table properties", "Advanced" tab and the "Stylesheet Classes" field.

I want to bring this field filled with the string "blue_table", which is the name of my CSS class. I'm working with the source of the "table" plugin. I have figured out how to change the value of fields like width and height, but the one I want is the "Stylesheet Classes" field.

Do any of you know to to set a default value for this field?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to edit the `ckeditor.js` file to customise the editor. You can add the following either to `config.js` and use it site wide or on any page where you're using CKEditor (inside a `script` tag as below, after the editor fields you're using).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {

        // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

        // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
        // interested on (the Table dialog).
        if ( dialogName == 'table' ) {

            // Set the tab
            var advTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'advanced'); 

            // Grab the field
            var stylesField = advTab.get('advCSSClasses');

            // Set the default value
            stylesField['default'] = 'blue_table';
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is modified from the [CKEditor documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Dialog_Customization). The hardest part is working out the IDs and names for all the fields used in the dialogs.

Comment: If you want to modify several fields and dialogs, you can simplify your code using this plugin: http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.es/2012/02/configuration-helper-for-ckeditor.html and as explained there, the best way to find the ids is to use the DevTools plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer. This property is in the dialogadvtab, in the property "advCSSClasses". The thing is that this plugin is inside the core js, I mean the ckeditor.js.

I had to do this :

```
children :
[
    {
        id : 'advCSSClasses',
        att : 'class',
        type : 'text',
        label : lang.cssClasses,
        'default' : 'blue_table',
        setup : setupAdvParams,
        commit : commitAdvParams
    }
]
```

The "problem" now is that I had to do it in the ckeditor.js, which is not a good practice. The problem is solved, but not int the best way.